# 400 (Bad Request) admin-ajax.php and WP Cost Estimation & Payment Forms Builder

Tags: wordpress, bad-request, admin-ajax

I have some problems with adamin-ajax.php - Console showing something like this:
[console screen](https://pli.io/2jiCkM.jpg)

I using few Wordpress plugins. The most important is: "WP Cost Estimation & Payment Forms Builder". Since yesturday I also using "WP Mail SMTP by WPForms" but I don't thing this plugin could make any problems with Ajax.

Suddenly Estimation form stoped passing - infinity loading page. Same on the backend in admin panel :(

The most interesting is that I did not makes any changes, only installed this SMTP plugin to solve mail problems.

Where can be a problem?

Comment: just guess it?. first check, which script make page load infinite by opening console -> network. next step is to clear cache, turn on debug log. without more details nobody can't help

Comment: As you can see on the image above the problem is inadmin-ajax.php in my opinion

Comment: Backend shows error with admin-ajax.php "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)"

Comment: the most popular 400 error of `admin-ajax.php` is not having `action` which will handle ajax request. but you mentioned infinite load of page, and just several plugin names. it's too broad. need more information like which request going too long, or returning 4xx, 5xx errors, what is your action for ajax request, which function handles it and why it's not exists( or working not right )  and etc

Comment: Oh no! It was QUOTA space on the server. OH MY GOD! :/